# Visualforce input type date picker field

Tags: visualforce, date, apexinputfield, date-picker

I am using date type field as `Input type` where serviceAssetItem is an instance of a `wrapper` class as follows:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ServiceAsset}" var="serviceAssetItem" id="assetListTable">
<apex:column headerValue="Sales Date">
    <apex:input type="date" value="{!serviceAssetItem.SalesDate}"/>
</apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

`Sales Date` field is displaying as follows:

[image: Sales Date]

If I have `SObject` like `objServiceAsset`, then using below code 'Sales Date` is showing like this.

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Add Item">
<apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:inputField value="{!objServiceAsset.Sales_Date__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

[image: SFDC Date Picker]

How can I have this `SFDC date picker` to be displayed in my first example where the object instance is not of `SOBject`.

Comment: You might have better luck with [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). You'll have to play around with which theme to use, but I imagine one of them is close.

Answer (score 2):

You might go to jQuery UI path as mentioned Adrian, but quite a bit of work to be honest. 
It's a bit ugly, but you could maybe use an existing custom object in your wrapper class that have a date field then populate that to your serviceAssetItem.SalesDate in the *get* method. 
So in the page you would use inputField as per normal sobject but you don't use serviceAssetItem.SalesDate you would use the date of your custom object in your warepper class.

**Controller**

```
public class MyWrapperClass{
   public String Name {get; set;}
   public Date SalesDate {get{ return dummy.My_Date__c;} set;}
   public MyObject__c dummy {get; set;}
}
```

**Page**

```
<apex:inputField value="{!serviceAssetItem.dummy.My_Date__c}"/>
```

Comment: In this case, if the SalesDate is blank then also it shows current date and trying to access the SalesDate it is showing "Attempt to de-reference a null object"